# Not able to pass -javaagent as JVM arg to Jetty 9

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty, jetty-9

I wanted to use jamm in our project. For that to be used, I have to pass '-javaagent:<..path...>/jamm-0.2.5.jar' as JVM args.

I am able to pass this argument in tomcat by adding the jar to tomcat/lib folder and modified startup.bat as follows:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -javaagent:"%CATALINA_HOME%\lib\jamm-0.2.5.jar"
call "%EXECUTABLE%" jpda start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

But I am not able to achieve the same in Jetty9. As done in Tomcat, I have copied the jamm-0.2.5.jar to jetty-distribution-9.2.3.v20140905/lib and added the following in startup.ini

```
--exec
-Xms1024m 
-Xmx1024m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
-Xdebug 
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y,suspend=n
-javaagent:E:\jetty-distribution-9.2.3.v20140905\lib\jamm-0.2.5.jar
```

It is not working. Also I tried removing this and adding it in jetty.sh

```
#####################################################
# Add jetty properties to Java VM options.
#####################################################
JAVA_OPTIONS+=("-Djetty.home=$JETTY_HOME" "-Djetty.base=$JETTY_BASE" "-Djava.io.tmpdir=$TMPDIR" "-javaagent:$JETTY_HOME/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar")
```

But it did not work. Where should I pass these jvm args in jetty? Can't I refer to JETTY_HOME the same way as I have done with TOMCAT_HOME in tomcat?

Note: I am working on Windows 8. Here is the output of java -jar start.jar --list-config:

```
Java Environment:
-----------------
 java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
 java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation 
 java.vm.version = 23.0-b21 
 java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
 java.vm.info = mixed mode
 java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
 java.runtime.version = 1.7.0_04-b22 
 java.io.tmpdir = C:\Users\PGULLA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ 
 user.dir = E:\jetty-distribution-9.2.3.v20140905
 user.language = en
 user.country = US 

Jetty Environment: 
-----------------
 jetty.version = 9.2.3.v20140905 
 jetty.home = E:\jetty-distribution-9.2.3.v20140905
 jetty.base = E:\jetty-distribution-9.2.3.v20140905

Config Search Order: 
-------------------- 
 <command-line> 
 ${jetty.base} -> E:\jetty-distribution-9.2.3.v20140905 
 ${jetty.home} -> E:\jetty-distribution-9.2.3.v20140905 


JVM Arguments:
--------------
 -Xms1024m
 -Xmx1024m
 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
 -Xdebug
 -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y,suspend=n
 -javaagent:E:\jetty-distribution-9.2.3.v20140905\lib\jamm-0.2.5.jar

 System Properties:
------------------
 (no system properties specified) 

Properties:
-----------
 http.timeout = 30000
 jetty.dump.start = false 
 jetty.dump.stop = false
 jetty.output.buffer.size = 32768 
 jetty.port = 8081
 jetty.request.header.size = 8192 
 jetty.response.header.size = 8192
 jetty.send.date.header = false
 jetty.send.server.version = true 
 jsp-impl = apache
 threads.max = 200
 threads.min = 10 
 threads.timeout = 60000

 Jetty Server Classpath:
-----------------------
Version Information on 35 entries in the classpath.
Note: order presented here is how they would appear on the classpath.
 changes to the --module=name command line options will be reflected here.
 0:0.2.5 | ${jetty.base}\lib\ext\jamm-0.2.5.jar
 1:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\apache-jsp\org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
 2: 3.8.2.v20130121-145325 | ${jetty.base}\lib\apache-jsp\org.eclipse.jetty.orbit.org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar
 3:8.0.9 | ${jetty.base}\lib\apache-jsp\org.mortbay.jasper.apache-el-8.0.9.M3.jar
 4: 2.3 | ${jetty.base}\lib\apache-jsp\org.mortbay.jasper.apache-jsp-8.0.9.M3.jar 
 5:1.2.1 | ${jetty.base}\lib\apache-jstl\org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.1.jar 
 6:1.2.1 | ${jetty.base}\lib\apache-jstl\org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.1.jar 
 7:(dir) | ${jetty.base}\resources 
 8:3.1.0 | ${jetty.base}\lib\servlet-api-3.1.jar
 9: 3.1.0.M0 | ${jetty.base}\lib\jetty-schemas-3.1.jar 
10:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\jetty-http-9.2.3.v20140905.jar 
11:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\jetty-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
12:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\jetty-xml-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
13:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\jetty-util-9.2.3.v20140905.jar 
14:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\jetty-io-9.2.3.v20140905.jar 
15:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\jetty-jndi-9.2.3.v20140905.jar 
16: 1.4.1.v201005082020 | ${jetty.base}\lib\jndi\javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar 
17: 1.2 | ${jetty.base}\lib\jndi\javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
18:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\jetty-security-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
19:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\jetty-servlet-9.2.3.v20140905.jar 
20:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\jetty-webapp-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
21:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\jetty-deploy-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
22:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\jetty-plus-9.2.3.v20140905.jar 
23:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\jetty-annotations-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
24:5.0.1 | ${jetty.base}\lib\annotations\asm-5.0.1.jar
25:5.0.1 | ${jetty.base}\lib\annotations\asm-commons-5.0.1.jar 
26: 1.2 | ${jetty.base}\lib\annotations\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
27: 1.0 | ${jetty.base}\lib\websocket\javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar
28:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\websocket\javax-websocket-client-impl-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
29:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\websocket\javax-websocket-server-impl-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
30:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\websocket\websocket-api-9.2.3.v20140905.jar
31:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\websocket\websocket-client-9.2.3.v20140905.jar 
32:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\websocket\websocket-common-9.2.3.v20140905.jar 
33:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\websocket\websocket-server-9.2.3.v20140905.jar 
34:9.2.3.v20140905 | ${jetty.base}\lib\websocket\websocket-servlet-9.2.3.v20140905.jar

Jetty Active XMLs:
------------------
 ${jetty.base}\etc\jetty.xml
 ${jetty.base}\etc\jetty-http.xml
 ${jetty.base}\etc\jetty-deploy.xml
 ${jetty.base}\etc\jetty-plus.xml
 ${jetty.base}\etc\jetty-annotations.xml
```

Comment: Your `startup.ini` path uses a Windows drive letter, so unless you're running `jetty.sh` in a Cygwin(-like) environment, that shell script won't have any effect and is for use in Unix-based environments.  If you are running in a "mixed" environment like that, it may be important to note those details in your question.

Comment: Updated my question. I am using Windows 8.

Comment: What command(s) are you executing to start Jetty?

Comment: In the Tomcat startup configuration that you claimed worked... you had double quotes (") around the path to the agent JAR.  Have you tried using them in the `startup.ini` file?  `-javaagent:"..."`

Comment: yes. it did not work. I got the following error:
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : E:\jetty-distribution-9.2.3.v20140905\lib\jamm-0.2.5.jar

Comment: That proves that the command line option is getting to the correct spot.  Now you need to focus on why the JVM doesn't think that your jamm JAR file is a valid JavaAgent.  You should be able to investigate that on the command line or maybe with a small test program (leaving Jetty alone until you figure it out).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61042/discussion-between-prasanthnath-and-william-price).

Comment: run `> java -jar start.jar --list-config` and post its output

Comment: Updated the output of command in the question.